# FactoryGirl Trait not registered: create error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I am updating an existing factories.rb in a project in order to add my own test cases for my developed module. But it's been a while whatever I do and change I keep getting this error of:

```
 Failure/Error: @topic = FactoryGirl.create(:topic)
 ArgumentError:
   Trait not registered: create
```

Here is how I call this create method:

```
before(:all) do
  @name = "user"
  @due_at = DateTime.now.in_time_zone + 1.minutes
  @topic = FactoryGirl.create(:topic)
  due_at1 = Time.parse(@due_at.to_s(:db))
  curr_time = DateTime.now.in_time_zone.to_s(:db)
  curr_time = Time.parse(curr_time)

  @time_in_min = Time.zone.now
end
```

These are relevant parts of my models:

```
class SignUpTopic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :signed_up_teams, foreign_key: 'topic_id', dependent: :destroy

class TopicDueDate < DueDate
  belongs_to :topic, class_name: 'SignUpTopic', foreign_key: 'parent_id'
```

And finaly factories.rb:

```
factory :topic, class: SignUpTopic do
  assignment

  topic_name "Hello world!"
  max_choosers 1
  category nil
  topic_identifier "1"
  micropayment 0
  private_to nil

  after(:create) do |signed_up_team|
    create_list(:signed_up_team, 1 , sign_up_topic: signed_up_team)
  end
end

factory :signed_up_team, class: SignedUpTeam do
  team
  topic

  is_waitlisted 0
  preference_priority_number nil
end
```

I have searched a lot over the internet, tried different ways of creating this association with FactoryGirl but mostly I get this error of "Trait not registered: create error" which I did not find anything about that, and at some approaches the error changed to something like "Attribute exists: Name already has been taken", which probably refers to topic_name field of SignUpTopic class.

Comment: Could you correct the typo in the question's title? You wrote "FacrotyGirl". Also, could you add the stack trace that you get? Could you add the code for the `assignment` factory? That might help find the answer.

Comment: fixed the title. when I make  after(:create) part as a comment error goes away. It is not about assignment

Comment: FactoryGirl.create is not the issue, after(:create) is not a valid method here as create is not identified as a trait. why exactly do you need after(:create) in factory defintion?

Comment: @shiladitya Why is `after(:create)` not a valid block? You can see it documented here: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#transient-attributes

Comment: @BardiaZamanian Please add more code to your question and a backtrace. Your code is using the `assignment`; `team`; `topic` factories. Without a backtrace it is very hard to help you.